# Write text on BITMAPINFO in memory

Tags: c++, image, bmp

I retrieve a frame from a .avi video as BITMAPINFO and I want to write a string on it, and I dont want to use OpenCV.I could write a library which manually changes the pixel color from the image , to form letters, but it would take a lot of time. The image is 32 bits RGBA

```
pbmi = (BITMAPINFO*)AVIStreamGetFrame(pgf, i);
BYTE *pPixelSrc = (sizeof(BITMAPINFO) + (BYTE*)pbmi);
long width,height;
width = *((long*)(((BYTE*)pbmi)+4));
height = *((long*)(((BYTE*)pbmi)+8));
//Draw string on data pPixelSrc
```

Comment: Why you don't want to use OpenCV? I now that you can learn by that, but if you are doing it for product it will be better to find some library (not necessarily OpenCV)

Answer (score 0):

Use the GDI function, or Gdiplus, to draw text with `DrawText` or `TextOut`. The bitmap could be upside down, it may have to be flipped. Check the sign for `height`

```
int width = pbmi->bmiHeader.biWidth;
int height = pbmi->bmiHeader.biHeight;

auto hdc = GetDC(0);
auto memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
auto hbitmap = CreateBitmap(width, height, 1, 32, pPixelSrc);
auto oldbmp = SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap);

TextOut(memdc, 0, 0, "123", 3);

SelectObject(memdc, oldbmp);
GetDIBits(memdc, hbitmap, 0, height, pPixelSrc, pbmi, 0);

DeleteObject(hbitmap);
DeleteDC(memdc);
ReleaseDC(0, hdc);
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed.Any way to change the text size?

Comment: Use `CreateFont` with a nice font name like `"Segoe UI"` and custom size, then `SelectObject(memdc, hfont)`. Make sure to call `DeleteObject(hfont)` when `hfont` is no longer needed. You have to familiars yourself with Windows GDI drawing functions.