# How to draw TrueType fonts into an array of pixels in WinAPI?

Tags: winapi, fonts, gdi, truetype

There are some WinAPI functions that draw TrueType fonts into a windows GDI context.

I want to have this TrueType text written, but into my own 2-dimensional array of pixels (the one I just blit onto a window with just this code :)

```
int blit_mode =  STRETCH_DELETESCANS; 

void BlitFrame() 
{ 
  BITMAPINFO bmi = {  {sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), frame_size_x, -frame_size_y,1,32,BI_RGB,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0} };
  SetStretchBltMode(hdc, blit_mode); 
  int result = StretchDIBits(hdc, 
             0, 0, client_x, client_y, 
             0, 0, frame_size_x, frame_size_y, 
             frame_bitmap, 
             &bmi, 
             DIB_RGB_COLORS, 
             SRCCOPY); 
}
```

This code is very messy in WinAPI and I couldn't find out (at least to this moment) how to do that.

How can I do that?

Comment: Search for "memory device context" and "device independent bitmap".

Comment: Petzold's "Programming Windows" explains bitmaps, device contexts, and how they relate. Understanding the concepts you are working with is an effective and efficient strategy going forward.

Comment: weird thing is : even if i will not render thise glyphs into my bitmap (which i dont know how to do and which is much welcome becouse then i could postprocess it wih my cpu etc) and i just blit my pixel table to window THEN render those text to window too - then it also dont work, it flickers... I dont understend why... it is all done in one paint routine and it does not seem to me it should be treated as a two separate repaints, even if there is small time space between those two drawings.. weird conclusion may be that windows do not buffers it until paint routine end but shows it real time

Comment: if so thats really weird.. then i need get those routines that render it into my array... byt why it is all so confusing and such a mess

Comment: It appears to be a mess to you, because you are refusing to do the ground work, and learn about the anatomy of the system you are working with. Read the [WM_PAINT message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/wm-paint) documentation to understand, why your solution exhibits flicker. Better yet, get Petzold's [Programming Windows®](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X). This is the most efficient way to learn Windows programming.

Comment: See this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51731891/4603670)

Answer (score 0):

tnx  Barmak Shemirani

i get your code and produced something like that

```
void BlitFrame2()
{

 BITMAPINFO bmi = {  {sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), frame_size_x, -frame_size_y,1,32,BI_RGB,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0} };


HDC  memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
HBITMAP  hbitmap = CreateBitmap(frame_size_x, frame_size_y, 1, 32, frame_bitmap);
HGDIOBJ  oldbmp = SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap);

SetBkMode(memdc, TRANSPARENT);
SetTextColor(memdc, 0xffffff);
TextOut(memdc, 0, 0, "123", 3);

SelectObject(memdc, oldbmp);
GetDIBits(memdc, hbitmap, 0, frame_size_y, frame_bitmap, &bmi, 0);
DeleteObject(hbitmap);
DeleteDC(memdc);

//  ReleaseDC(0, hdc);

SetStretchBltMode(hdc, blit_mode);

int result = StretchDIBits(hdc,
             0, 0, client_x, client_y,
             0, 0, frame_size_x, frame_size_y,
             frame_bitmap,
             &bmi,
             DIB_RGB_COLORS,
             SRCCOPY);
}
```

its adds stable text to my blitted frames, tnx

hovever i would get yet some question as i dont understand it

1) could maybe someone tell me a bit more how it works and where memory transfers are? do i have simple byte acces to this pixel table that is updated with drawed text? (for example to postprocess it)

2) it works but it gets slower quite noticably, for example when my oryginal frame was 2 ms (draw some bitmap sprite then blit) when using this tame grows up to 8 ms

3) can i move some of those calls outside of frame loop?

PS
when thinking on this i assume it works like that
1) it copies my pixel table in memdc at some point (where?)
2) it draws to this memdc those fonts
3) GetDIBits updates my oryginal pixel table with changed pixels (im not sure as to this hovever, but almost sure)
4) i blit it just like before

if so instead of one blit i get three (co it should be 3 times slower,
measurements show its more like 4 times, but maybe its an measurment error (2 and 8 may be 2.7 and 8.1 for example)

if this is three it would be ok, hovever i think i not always would need to get those table pixels reupdated from memdc, is there a way of
blitting it stright from memdc? (then it would be only two times slower instead of 3, still it is sad those fount routines cant just render stright into my own ram table - then it would be no slower at all) (isnt it really possible?)

Comment: What is your goal? You can use memory dc to draw on a bitmap. You can also use memory dc as a paint buffer. `BitBlit` or `StretchBlt` to skip `BITMAPINFO` functions. The usage of `hdc` seems wrong. `hdc` is a temporary handle, it can be passed around, but it shouldn't be kept - By the way, you can update the question, or delete the answer and the question, ask a new question instead.

Comment: The GDI font rendering routines *can* render straight into a device context, backed by an in-memory bitmap. To see this, one needs to understand [device contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/device-contexts).